# R errors indirect calling of argument

Tags: r, functional-programming

This is one of examples when `'['` error occurs :

```
> libs=.packages(TRUE)
> library(help=libs[1])
Błąd w poleceniu 'find.package(pkgName, lib.loc, verbose = verbose)':
  nie ma pakietu o nazwie ‘[’
```

`R` behaves differently when I use argument directly `library(help="base")` versus indirect use : `x="base"; library(help=x)`, why `R` thinks I ask about `x` packages, what mechanism is used ? I think solution is somewhere here : http://adv-r.had.co.nz/

Comment: `library(help=get(libs[1])) `does not make the trick, as `R` asks for `get` package

Comment: Blame the [NSE](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) here

Comment: `library(help=libs[1],character.only=TRUE)` should work

Comment: @Tensibai what is universal solution - when there is no `character.only` argument ?

Comment: You mean avoiding NSE ? none I know of, depends on witch function and if it use NSE or not, and if it allows a switch to disable NSE.

Comment: You can play with [this chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#substitute) code. With your `x` example: `eval(substitute(library(help=y), list(y=x)))`

Comment: You could, also, use workarounds that evaluate arguments before being passed to the function -- e.g. `do.call` and `call`: `do.call("library", list(help = x))`; `eval(call("library", help = x))`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of `library`, you will find the following code

```
if (!character.only) 
    help <- as.character(substitute(help))
```

The help to `substitute` says that

> substitute returns the parse tree for the (unevaluated) expression expr, substituting any variables bound in env

where `env` means the current evaluation environment. But `libs` is bound in `.GlobalEnv` and not in the environment of the function `library`.

A simple example of what you are doing

```
x="a"
test_fun=function(x) {
  as.character(substitute(x))
}
test_fun(x)
#"x"
```

However, if `x` was defined within the function body

```
#delete previous definition of x, if necessary
#rm(list="x")
test_fun=function(x) {
  x="a"
  as.character(substitute(x))
}
test_fun(x)
#"a"
```

One interesting aspect can be read further down the help of `substitute`

> Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in env, it is unchanged. If it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function or explicitly created using delayedAssign(), the expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol. If it is an ordinary variable, its value is substituted, unless env is .GlobalEnv in which case the symbol is left unchanged.

The last part "unless env is .GlobalEnv in which case the symbol is left unchanged" is interesting because

```
x="a"
as.character(substitute(x))
"x"
```

This is because `env` is `.GlobalEnv` in this case. Then, substitution does not take place. I am sure there is a good reason for this - still it is somewhat surprising for me.